# Changing property of label with a function does not work

Tags: android, mobile

I try to change the backgroundcolor of a label, by clicking on a button.
I've looked into this issue with my teacher, but we can't find the problem, everything seems to be normal. If I try to push an alert, this does work, so it is not the eventhandler that is not working.

```
var label = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    backgroundColor:'#00ff00',
    width:120,
    height:200,
    top:20
});

var btnRed = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title:'Red',
    top:250,
    height:50,
    width:100,
});

btnRed.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    label.backgroundColor:'#ff0000'
});
```

[image: Error message received]

Comment: What are you using to write this? And what is Titanium?

Comment: Titanium is common platform that support iphone and android app both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "=" instead of ":" for an assignment.

```
btnRed.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    label.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing...

```
label.backgroundColor:'#ff0000'
```

to

```
label.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
```

I believe this will work because in the upper section, you are creating an object with properties, so you can use the property : value syntax, but in the function you need to access and set the value by using the normal = operator.